# Create a virtual machine programmatically using Virtual Box SDK

Tags: c++, virtualbox

I am trying to create programmatically a virtual machine and install in it an operating system.
To do this, I installed VirtualBox, run it and leave it open.
To create the "client" application I used from Virtual Box SDK the "mscom" sample that is done in C++ and makes a demo on how to interrogate virtual machines from the Virtual Box running. This demo works, i tested it with some machines created from Vbox and it worked.
I read the documentation and the most relevant method that I found to create a virtual machine is: "VirtualBox::createMachine()":

So I wrote this:

```
bool createNewMachine(IVirtualBox *virtualBox)
{
   BSTR hostOSName = SysAllocString(L"Windows");
   BSTR machineName = SysAllocString(L"Test");
   IMachine *machine = NULL;
   rc = virtualBox->CreateMachine(NULL, machineName, NULL, hostOSName, NULL, &machine);
   //rc returns -2135228415 - FAILED
}
```

Did somebody already used this Virtual Box SDK and done this, anybody got any idea on what should be the lifecycle of a machine creation, maybe this is what I'm doing wrong. Thank you

Comment: How do you plan on "programatically" installing an OS in the VM?

Comment: @SJuan76 Not knowing what the SDK is capable of, possibly with input simulation? I don't see why it *shouldn't* be possible. E.g. install it once manually, record all input events, replay it. Or by cloning a virtual disc.

Comment: I don;t know what this SDK can provide, I'm thinking this is all about..manipulating this virtual machine instances, I see no other use of it, so I think it must be possible, I don't want to programatically do every step of the installation, just create a virtual machine, allocate resources for it and start an installation, the installation itself will be done by the user.Thank you